# remove \n after replace " " in kdb+

Tags: kdb

I have a table named "t", with the column, "x". It looks as follows:

```
     `INPUT:"\n This is sample code"
     RESULT: "This is sample code"`
```

**I want to remove \n in particular table column values**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to use `ssr` to achieve the desired trimming you require in a table setting:

```
q)t:([]a:1 2 3;b:("\nThis is sample code";"More good sample code";"\n More sample code"))
q)t
a b
-------------------------
1 "\nThis is sample code"
2 "More good sample code"
3 "\n More sample code"
q)@[t;`b;{trim ssr[x;"\n";""]}@']
a b
-------------------------
1 "This is sample code"
2 "More good sample code"
3 "More sample code"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is neither a table nor a column, but with what you have, here are two ways to do the required:

```
q)INPUT:"\n This is sample code"
q)trim INPUT except "\n"
"This is sample code"
q)trim ssr[INPUT;"\n";""]
"This is sample code"
```

Comment: @santhoshv Could you provide an example of your actual table? It's not very clear from the example you provided what you want